# Subscribe callback triggers twice when use computed with notify and rateLimit extender

Tags: knockout.js

When I use computed notify='always' and rateLimit extender, subscribe callback triggers twice.

```
    ko.changedFlag = function(root) {
    var result = function() {};
    var initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root));

    result.isChanged = ko.computed(function() {
        var changed = initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
        if (changed) result.reset();
        return changed;
    }).extend({ notify: 'always',rateLimit:500 });

    result.reset = function() {
        initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
    };

    return result;
};
// add changed flag property to the model
model.changedFlag = new ko.changedFlag(model);
// subscribe to changes
model.changedFlag.isChanged.subscribe(function(isChanged) {
    if (isChanged)  alert("model changed");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GQgpX/39/

- Press "add" key or type something to textbox and see result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `reset` within your computed (which modifies an observable that the computed already depends on) is causing the extraneous notification in this case.

You may want to do something like:

```
result.isChanged = ko.computed(function() {        
    return initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
}).extend({ notify: 'always', rateLimit: 500 });

result.isChanged.subscribe(function(changed) {
    if (changed) {
       result.reset();   
    }
});
```

Your subscription will still get called twice with the first time being when the flag indicates a change and the second with `isChanged` as `false` from the `reset` call.

Comment: How come it only does this when you use both `notify` and `rateLimit` together?  Taking either one of them out doesn't cause a problem

Comment: @JamesThorpe ya i feel the same . RP can you clue me on this .

Comment: I stepped through it for a few minutes. Normally changes to an observable inside of a computed that already depends on that observable do not trigger re-evaluation (otherwise it could re-evaluate recursively). Looks like in the case that it is rate-limited though, we end up queueing up a re-evaluation (for after the timeout period). After the timeout, when it accesses the computed's value, it doesn't believe that it needs to re-evaluate, so it returns the current value. The `notify: "always"` shows this, as otherwise the second notification would be suppressed.

Comment: Overall, it is a better practice to not modify observables inside of a computed that depends on that observable. I would recommend not modifying observables at all within a computed's evaluator and subscribe to it, if necessary. Hope that helps!